# How can I get the count of other users mentioned in tweets by a particular user using Twitter API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I am looking to get the count of how many users were mentioned by a particular user in its tweets for a specific period of time.

I am looking to achieve it in Twitter API 1.1

For example, an arbitrary user @user1 mentioned 20 users in his tweets since last 10 days.

Comment: Please take a look to the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public). Probably the best would be to use [GET user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) and then count user mentions.

Comment: Thanks, Anyways I have written the custom logic to count the number of users mentioned in tweets using LinQ and regex matches.